# How to identify "scale" of display from browser-standard properties?

Tags: android, html, css, linux, firefox

I've been told by each of Web Applications and Software Engineering that this question should be posted here.  I hope so.

I converted a book PDF into an HTML file, to read that on a tablet with specific colour styling and other look and feel.  That was the first.  I want to convert my entire book library into a uniform set of docs for reading.

I got it all sorted out for the desktop (**Firefox 114.0.1 on UbuntuMATE 20.04**), but when I try it on my Acer B3-A20 tablet (also running **Firefox 68.8.1 on Android 5.1**), I encounter 2 things which are undesirable.

1 - It seems that the tablet's display **PixelsPerInch** is denser than my desktop monitor.  I would like to know **how I could obtain that value from the browser's properties and values** which are set during the browser startup on the tablet/desktop/other.  I would then use that value in my @media rules in order to choose/define CSS rules that will apply the "**em**" in a manner that will physically display identically on both desktop and tablet. Currently, "em" values in a fixed stylesheet are **being physically rendered as "scaled-down" compared to the desktop**.  I want to come up with a way (*without resorting to external APIs like WURFL*) to correctly map the physical sizing of output displayed with a ratio of 1:1 with the desktop display.

2 - The browser's built-in default font for each platform is different.  I can set for the Desktop (user-defined settings), but I am unable to set that for the browser-only on the tablet (don't want to tamper with the tablet's Android global settings).  No option to do so is offered by Firefox for this version on Android.  Can I somehow set that property to a specific value, thru **about:config** on the tablet?  I know I could set that using CSS rules, but again, I would need to correctly identify/set the profile based on findings from issue 1 above.

Less critical, but desirable, I would like to know how to define the CSS so that ... when the browser is made narrower, the look of the TOC should not go from **state [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BXXLG.png)** to **state [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PbQwP.png)**, but instead keeps the chapter title on the same line with the chapter number, but that the chapter title becomes itself multi-line under its own column. *I was hoping to avoid use of a table definition.*

**Image of state 1:**
[image]

**Image of state 2:**
[image]

As it stands, the physical rendering on the tablet appears to be only about 70% of the physical size of the desktop rendering, for reasons I don't quite understand, other that *the Pixels per Inch is visually definitely different between the two*.

On Android, I don't know which of the **font.minimum-size*** which should apply to my context.

Also on Android, I don't know which of the **font.name-list.*** (font.name-list.sans-serif.x-unicode, font.name-list.sans-serif.x-western, font.name-list.serif.x-unicode, font.name-list.serif.x-western) would provide a minimum necessary set of parameters to control and obtain the desired effects.

I also saw a parameter named **font.size.inflation.emPerLine** (and other **font.size.inflation*** parameters).  I have no clue how I could make those work for me.

What are **font.size.variable.x-unicode**/**x-western** used for?

One parameter, **reader.font_size** has a value of **5**, which did not seem to have relevance to my problem, but I might be wrong.

Also, **reader.font_type** is set to **sans-serif**.  Is that controlling the default "style" that I am seeing when the HTML is displayed on the Tablet?

One mystery is the **browser.viewport.desktopWidth** parameter having a value of 980, when the device info details reports Horizontal pixels as 1280 and Vertical pixels of 800.  Not sure why Firefox would report that.

Please note,  the HTML with the line

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

seems to behave worse than for the same HTML without that line, but they both behave with scaling down all of the fonts to smaller than what I had specfied while viewing on the Desktop!!!

**HTML for TOC:**

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
  <title>Pebble in the Sky</title>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"> 
  <link href="stylesheet.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
  <link href="page_styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
</head>
<body class="oasismega"> 

<div class="userblock">
  <p class="chapterhead" id="TOCpage">
    <span class="chapternumber"><b>&nbsp;&nbsp;Contents&nbsp;&nbsp;</b></span>
    <br class="userblock"/>
  </p> 

  <div class="userblock" width="100%">
    <span class="chaptercontentitemid"><b>1</b></span>
    <span class="chaptercontentitemtitle"><a class="toc" href="#chpt-001">between one footstep and the next</a></span>
  </div> 

  <div class="userblock" width="100%">
    <span class="chaptercontentitemid"><b>2</b></span>
    <span class="chaptercontentitemtitle"><a class="toc" href="#chpt-002">the disposal of a stranger</a></span>
  </div> 

  <div class="userblock" width="100%">
    <span class="chaptercontentitemid"><b>3</b></span>
    <span class="chaptercontentitemtitle"><a class="toc" href="#chpt-003">one world ―― or many?</a></span>
  </div> 
</div>

</body></html>
```

**Partial HTML for chapter:**

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
  <title>Pebble in the Sky</title>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"> 
  <link href="stylesheet.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
  <link href="page_styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
</head>
<body class="oasismega"> 

<div class="userblock">
  <p class="chapterhead" id="chpt-001">
    <span class="chapternumber"><b>&nbsp;&nbsp;1&nbsp;&nbsp;</b></span>
    <br class="userblock"/>
    <span class="chaptertitle"><a class="chp" href="#TOCpage">between one footstep and the next</a></span>
    <br class="userblock"/>
  </p> 

<p class="chapterfirstparagraph">Two minutes before he disappeared forever from the face of the Earth he knew, Joseph Schwartz strolled along the pleasant streets of suburban Chicago quoting Browning to himself.</p>
<p class="paragraphstartindent">In a sense this was strange, since Schwartz would scarcely have impressed any casual passer-by as the Browning-quoting type. He looked exactly what he was: a retired tailor, thoroughly lacking in what the sophisticates of today call a “formal education.” Yet he had expended much of an inquisitive nature upon random reading. By the sheer force of indiscriminate voracity, he had gleaned a smattering of practically everything, and by means of a trick memory had managed to keep it all straight.</p>
<p class="paragraphstartindent">For instance, he had read Robert Browning’s Rabbi Ben Ezra twice when he was younger, so, of course, knew it by heart. Most of it was obscure to him, but those first three lines had become one with the beating of his heart these last few years. He intoned them to himself, deep within the silent fortress of his mind, that very sunny and very bright early summer day of 1949:</p>
</div>

</body></html>
```

**stylesheet.css:**

```
body {
    display:    block;
    width:      auto;   /*600px; */
    box-sizing: border-box;
    line-height:    1.3em;
    margin:     0;
    padding:    0;
    color:      #DFAF6F;
    background-color:   black;
}
a:link.toc  { text-decoration: none; color: #DFAF6F; }
a:link.chp  { text-decoration: none; color: #4F4FCF; }
a:visited.toc   { text-decoration: none; color: #DFAF6F; }
a:visited.chp   { text-decoration: none; color: #4F4FCF; }
a:hover.toc { text-decoration: none; color: #DFAF6F; }
a:hover.chp { text-decoration: none; color: #4F4FCF; }
a:active.toc    { text-decoration: none; color: #DFAF6F; }
a:active.chp    { text-decoration: none; color: #4F4FCF; }

img {
    display:    block;
    max-width:  100%;
    height:     auto;
    }
.bold {
    font-weight: bold;
    }
.oasismega {            /* calibre */
    display: block;
    font-size:      1.0em;
    line-height:    1.4em;
    text-align:     justify;
    margin-top:     0;
    margin-right:   0;
    margin-bottom:  0;
    margin-left:    0;
    padding-top:    0;
    padding-right:  0;
    padding-bottom: 0;
    padding-left:   0;
    }
.userblock {            /* calibre1 */
    display: block;
    width:      100%;
    font-size:      1.0em;
    line-height:    1.2em;
    }
.coverartwork {
    display: block;
    object-fit:     contain;
    object-position:    center;
    margin-top:     0;
    margin-right:   0;
    margin-bottom:  0;
    margin-left:    0;
    padding-top:    0;
    padding-right:  0;
    padding-bottom: 0;
    padding-left:   0;
    }
.titlepageauthor {          /* chapterhead */
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    text-indent: 0;
    margin-top:     0;
    margin-right:   0;
    margin-bottom:  0;
    margin-left:    0;
    padding-top:    2.5em;
    padding-right:  30px;   /* extra */
    padding-bottom: 6.0em;
    padding-left:   30px;
    }
.titlepageauthorname {          /* chapternumber */
    text-align: center;
    text-indent: 0;
    font-size:      2.0em;
    font-style:     bold;
    line-height:    2.0em;
    color:      #DFAF6F;
    }
.titlepagewords {           /* chapterhead */
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    text-indent: 0;
    margin-top:     0;
    margin-right:   0;
    margin-bottom:  0;
    margin-left:    0;
    padding-top:    1.5em;
    padding-right:  30px;   /* extra */
    padding-bottom: 1.0em;
    padding-left:   30px;
    }
.titlepageothers {          /* chapterhead */
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    text-indent: 0;
    margin-top:     0;
    margin-right:   0;
    margin-bottom:  0;
    margin-left:    0;
    padding-top:    0;
    padding-right:  30px;   /* extra */
    padding-bottom: 0;
    padding-left:   30px;
    }
.titlepageseries {          /* chaptertitle */
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    text-indent: 0;
    font-size:      1.2em;
    font-style:     bold;
    line-height:    1.2em;
    padding-top:    0;
    padding-right:  30px;   /* extra */
    padding-bottom: 10em;
    padding-left:   40px;
    color:      #DFAF6F;
    }
.titlepagetitle {           /* chapternumber */
    text-align: center;
    text-indent: 0;
    font-size:      2.5em;
    font-style:     bold;
    line-height:    1.4em;
    color:      #DFAF6F;
    }
.titlepagepublisherimprint {        /* chapternumber */
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    text-indent: 0;
    font-size:      1.0em;
    font-style:     bold;
    line-height:    1.1em;
    padding-top:    0.4em;
    padding-right:  30px;   /* extra */
    padding-bottom: 0.3em;
    padding-left:   30px;
    color:      #DFAF6F;
    }
.titlepagepublisherlocation {       /* chapternumber */
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    text-indent: 0;
    font-size:      0.9em;
    font-style:     bold;
    line-height:    1.0em;
    padding-top:    0.3em;
    padding-right:  30px;   /* extra */
    padding-bottom: 2.5em;
    padding-left:   30px;
    color:      #DFAF6F;
    }
.copyrightshead {           /* chapterhead */
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
    text-indent: 0;
    margin-top:     0;
    margin-right:   0;
    margin-bottom:  0;
    margin-left:    0;
    padding-top:    2em;
    padding-right:  30px;   /* extra */
    padding-bottom: 2em;
    padding-left:   30px;
    }
.copyrightslabel {          /* chapternumber */
    font-size:      2.0em;
    font-style:     bold;
    line-height:    2.0em;
    color:      black;
    background-color:   #2F2F8F;
    }
.copyrightswords {          /* chapterhead */
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
    text-indent: 0;
    font-size:      0.9em;
    line-height:    1.1em;
    margin-top:     0;
    margin-right:   0;
    margin-bottom:  0;
    margin-left:    0;
    padding-top:    0.15em;
    padding-right:  0px;    /* extra */
    padding-bottom: 0.15em;
    padding-left:   0px;
    }
.copyrightsdeclare {            /* chapterhead */
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
    text-indent: 0;
    font-size:      0.9em;
    line-height:    1.1em;
    padding-top:    2em;
    padding-right:  0px;    /* extra */
    padding-bottom: 2em;
    padding-left:   30px;
    color:      #DFAF6F;
    }
.booksummary {              /* chaptertitle */
    display: block;
    font-size:      0.9em;
    line-height:    1.3em;
    font-style:     bold;
    padding-top:    0em;
    padding-bottom: 0em;
    padding-right:  30px;   /* extra */
    padding-left:   30px;

    color:      #DFAF6F;
    }
.dedicationhead {           /* chapterhead */
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
    text-indent: 0;
    margin-top:     0;
    margin-right:   0;
    margin-bottom:  0;
    margin-left:    0;
    padding-top:    2em;
    padding-right:  30px;   /* extra */
    padding-bottom: 2em;
    padding-left:   30px;
    }
.dedicationlabel {          /* chapternumber */
    font-size:      2.0em;
    font-style:     bold;
    line-height:    2.0em;
    color:      black;
    background-color:   #2F2F8F;
    }
.dedicationwords {          /* chapterhead */
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
    text-indent: 0;
    margin-top:     0;
    margin-right:   0;
    margin-bottom:  0;
    margin-left:    0;
    padding-top:    2em;
    padding-right:  30px;   /* extra */
    padding-bottom: 2em;
    padding-left:   30px;
    }
.dedication {               /* chaptertitle */
    font-size:      1.0em;
    font-style:     bold;
    line-height:    1.4em;
    color:      #DFAF6F;
    }
.chapterhead {          /* calibre_ */
    display: block;
    text-align: right;
    text-indent: 0;
    margin-top:     0;
    margin-right:   0;
    margin-bottom:  0;
    margin-left:    0;
    padding-top:    2em;
    padding-right:  60px;   /* extra */
    padding-bottom: 0;
    padding-left:   30px;
    }
.chaptercontentitemid {
    display:        inline-block;
    width:      4em;
    text-align:     right;
    font-size:      1.2em;
    font-style:     bold;
    line-height:    1.3em;
    color:      #DFAF6F;
    }
.chaptercontentitemidw {
    display:        inline-block;
    width:      10em;
    text-align:     right;
    font-size:      0.9em;
    font-style:     bold;
    line-height:    1.0em;
    color:      #DFAF6F;
    }
.chaptercontentitemtitle {
    display:        inline-block;
    width:      auto;
    text-align:     left;
    font-size:      1.2em;
    font-style:     bold;
    line-height:    1.3em;
    padding-left:   30px;
    color:      #DFAF6F;
    }
.chaptercontentitempage {
    display:        inline-block;
    float:      right;
    width:      4em;
    text-align:     right;
    font-size:      1.2em;
    font-style:     bold;
    line-height:    1.3em;
    padding-right:  30px;
    color:      #DFAF6F;
    }
.chaptertitle {         /* calibre4 */
    font-size:      1.4em;
    font-style:     bold;
    line-height:    1.5em;
    color:      #4F4FCF;
    }
.chapternumber {            /* calibre4 */
    font-size:      2.0em;
    font-style:     bold;
    line-height:    2.1em;
    color:      black;
    background-color:   #2F2F8F;
    }
.chapterfirstparagraph {    /* calibre_3 */
    display: block;
    text-indent: 0;
    text-align: justify;
    font-size:      1.0em;
    line-height:    1.4em;
    margin-top:     0;
    margin-right:   0;
    margin-bottom:  0;
    margin-left:    0;
    padding-top:    2em;    /* extra */
    padding-right:  30px;
    padding-bottom: 0.15em;
    padding-left:   30px;
    }
.paragraphstartindent {     /* from chapterfirstparagraph */
    display: block;
    text-indent: 2em;
    text-align: justify;
    font-size:      1.0em;
    line-height:    1.4em;
    margin-top:     0;
    margin-right:   0;
    margin-bottom:  0;
    margin-left:    0;
    padding-top:    0.15em;
    padding-right:  30px;
    padding-bottom: 0.15em;
    padding-left:   30px;
    }
.sectionbreak {
    display: block;
    text-align:     center;
    margin-top:     0;
    margin-right:   0;
    margin-bottom:  0;
    margin-left:    0;
    padding-top:    1em;    /* extra */
    padding-right:  30px;
    padding-bottom: 1em;    /* extra */
    padding-left:   30px;
    font-size:      1.5em;
    font-weight:    normal;
    font-style:     normal;
    color:      #4F4FCF;
    }
.paragraphquote {
    display: block;
    margin-top:     0;
    margin-right:   0;
    margin-bottom:  0;
    margin-left:    0;
    padding-top:    0.8em;
    padding-right:  30px;
    padding-bottom: 0.8em;
    padding-left:   6em;    /* extra */
    }
.paragraphquoteindent {     /* from chapterfirstparagraph */
    display: block;
    text-indent:    0;
    text-align: justify;
    font-size:      1.0em;
    line-height:    1.4em;
    font-style:     italic;
    color:      #9F9FFF;
    margin-top:     0;
    margin-right:   0;
    margin-bottom:  0;
    margin-left:    0;
    padding-top:    0;
    padding-right:  0;
    padding-bottom: 0;
    padding-left:   0;
    }
.storyend {         /* from chapterhead */
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    text-indent: 0;
    margin-top:     0;
    margin-right:   0;
    margin-bottom:  0;
    margin-left:    0;
    padding-top:    2em;
    padding-right:  30px;
    padding-bottom: 2em;
    padding-left:   30px;
    background-color:   black;
    }
```

**page_style.css**

```
@page {
    margin-bottom: 5pt;
    margin-top: 5pt
    }
```

EDIT:

I came upon an approach that might work for me, but it seems to have no effect, even when selecting different values from the drop-down menu on the Desktop Firefox.

The HTML coding I used is:

```
<link href="stylesheetBaseline.css" rel="stylesheet" /> <link href="stylesheetDefault.css" rel="stylesheet" title="Desktop Styling" /> <link href="stylesheetAndroid.css" rel="alternate stylesheet" title="Android Styling" /> <link href="stylesheetOther.css" rel="alternate stylesheet" title="Other Styling" />
```

I placed that in the header of my HTML, and was able to see the menu options[3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rRbmC.png), but changing the selection did not apply any changes other than when I selected the "None" option.  When I went back to choose any one of the others, I got the same display rendering result for all of them.  Why is that, when the only size specified with pixels is the body font size and it is different for every one of the 4 stylesheets ???

[image: Choosing alternative stylesheet from browser menu]

Comment: While I'm still interpreting your issue(s), some info: Desktop browser default font size `16px`, Android (as I recall, been a while..) `14px` or even `12px`, so there's your first difference. For all browsers: `1in = 96px` and `1px = 1/96th of 1in`, [W3C Absolute Lengths](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-values-4/#absolute-lengths). These are software pixels, regardless of PPI which are hardware pixels. PPI = 1200px is just sharper than PPI = 300px, the pixel in the browser will still be 1/96th of 1in. In hardware you would get e.g. 1200PPI/96px=12.5 hardware pixels used to display 1 browser pixel.

Comment: Hope this makes sense... Don't mix software (browser) and hardware (device) pixel calculations. It is a 'black hole' very little developers seem to be able to return from... In Android PPI is used to determine which graphic files (icons) to display (med, hd, qhd, uhd, etc.). But in both phone, tablet as well as desktop browsers W3C specs apply.

Comment: Here's a simple page I created some time ago to test the accuracy of `1cm` and `1in` in a desktop browser [link](https://renevanderlende.one/discord-stuff/accurate-centimer.html). The two squares should stay the same size regardless of the browser zoom factor and actually do measure 1cm and 1in with an ol'school handheld ruler.

Comment: Thank you, Rene! (or is that René?)  I copied the html for the page provided by your link onto my tablet.  It confirmed I was not crazy.  I physically measured with a rule, and the 1" box is 5/8" square, even when the page reports:   dpr: 1.000 device pixelratio.  It is also reporting fs: 16px root font-size, but that is obviously all improperly scaled.  So my tablet must have a bug in the OS, but I am not about to do an update on that now legacy device unsupported by Acer.  Is there a Mozilla built-in modifiable, using about:config, to scale up all display rendering by 1.6 (1"/.625") ? zmf=1.

Comment: Please note that the tablet is showing browser.viewport.defaultZoom = -1 .

Comment: Interestingly enough, while the zmf is reported as 1 for the Tablet, the zmf is reported as 1.331 on the Desktop !!!  Also, fs is reporting as 16 px font size for both Tablet and Desktop.

Comment: For your peace of mind: my W10-x64 Chrome says zmf: 1.000, Edge: 0.000 and Firefox: 1.008. All with default browser settings. Lesson: better make sure your page takes proper care of responsiveness. You cannot control all the settings of all devices in the world. ...accent aigu...

Comment: Thank you again, @Rene.  So, **is there an existing browser config parameter** that will permit me to uniquely identify the environment the browser is in so that I can "choose/enable" one context-specific stylesheet from a set of pre-defined stylesheets suited to each context?  Can you point me to some ECMAscript snippet of code (placed in HTML header) that would show me how to probe that parameter, evaluate and compare for selection, then set the "link" for the chosen stylesheet file? I feel I can adapt existing code.  I am NOT a Javascript programmer.  BTW, my tool is a multi-phase bash.

Comment: Maybe I am grasping for straws here but ... could I use something like `<select>
    <optgroup label = "Choose the 'stylesheet.css' for your environment:">
    <option stylesheet="stylesheetDesktop.css">Desktop</option>    
 <option stylesheet="stylesheetAndroid.css">Android</option>    
    </optgroup>
</select>` to select the desired stylesheet, and have that option offered in a popup upon the opening of the HTML page in the browser (**no remote server, only local files**)?

Comment: Possibly better, I came upon this approach (https://mdn.github.io/css-examples/alt-style-sheets/): `<link href="commonBaseline.css" rel="stylesheet" /> <link href="contextDefault.css" rel="stylesheet" title="Desktop Styling" /> <link href="contextAndroid.css" rel="alternate stylesheet" title="Android Styling" /> <link href="contextOther.css" rel="alternate stylesheet" title="Other Styling" />` . I just don't know how to make the selection via embedded Javascript in the HTML header.  **BUT** there is no option to click on a "View" option in the options menu on Android Firefox!!!

Comment: For security reasons you cannot access browser config from a html page. However,  maybe `<link media="min-width: ...">` for selected styles will work for you. Both `<link>` and `<style>` support the *media* attribute with the same functionality as `@media`. You can add `<link>` for different devices this way. [MDN: Using media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_media_queries/Using_media_queries) says *To target specific media...* in the first paragraph. Take it from there.

Comment: Thank you, René.  We are back to where I originally began. What is the parameter that I can identify in standalone HTML header that will tell me that I am on a Linux or Android platform?  I can then use that for the @media query definition that will let me set the BODY font size for each context.  If it involves javascript code that must be standalone embedded code in the HEAD section, not generated by a server creating a page.

Comment: I can't use dimensional values for the [@media], as the link you provided revealed that the rendering is scaled-down, because the values which should give me 1" give me only 5/8". I've used @media before, but never for anything that needs a probe to get the parameter from a browser default, or the OS default.  I could define a custom parameter using the browser's about:config, and set it to "Android" or better yet to "1.6" the scaling that I need to apply to get proper rendering. But first I need a method to uniquely identify that I am on the Android so that I can evaluate that with [@media].

Comment: This was taken offline as a chat.